# What vectors in the plane z=x are orthogonal to $(1,-1,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I believe all such vectors should be of the form $(a,b,a)$. Hence, 
$$ (a,b,a) \cdot (1,-1,0) = a - b + 0 = 0 \implies a=b$$
So all the vectors we seek are of the form
$$ (a,a,a)$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your correct, the set is $\{(a,a,a)\in\mathbb{R}^3:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is approach is correct.